# How to use Redux Form Wizard with permanent URLS per page

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-form

I'm working to build a signup > profile setup flow for a new application which is using React + Redux.

I found the following example for a redux form wizard:

http://redux-form.com/6.7.0/examples/wizard/

This seems to be the closest example but the problem is each step in the wizard does not change the URL, so if the user clicks the browser's forward/back btn or refreshes their browser, it will break.

Would it be OK to make Redux form wizard have permanent URLs? How can I approach this as a beginner?

Something where the wizard has URLs like:

```
/wizard/name
/wizard/profile
/wizard/photo
```

Comment: What's the right way to do this in react... Should each of the above URLs be a separate component or all live in one component?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Would it be OK to make Redux form wizard have permanent URLs?

The way how it's implemented depends on every use case. I don't see any problem why it wouldn't be ok.

The [wizard example](http://redux-form.com/6.7.0/examples/wizard/) tells you everything you need to know regarding your approach.

Talking about the official example, you could approach this in the following way:

- Create a `/wizard/name` route which would render the same `WizardForm.js` component;
- If the subpath is `/name`, render the `WizardFormFirstPage`
- Same for the other subpaths.

Answer (score 3):

I recently implemented a redux-form wizard with client-side routing. I will share some of the details here for posterity...

I have a component called MainContent which has several React-Router 4 routes. One of these routes looks like this:

`<Route path={'/profile/:profileSection'} component={Profile} />`.

This route loads a "wizard" style redux-form that the user fills out to set up her profile.

Note the `profileSection` route parameter. If the current URL is:
`https://www.myawesomeapp.com/profile/my-age`, the Profile component will receive a `profileSection` prop from the router with a (string) value of `'my-age'`. This would be used to load the form "step" that asks the user her age.

Profile is a stateful component. Its render method returns the wrapped components for each step. It looks roughly this like this:

```
    return (
        <div>
            <Step1 {...this.state} {...this.props} />
            <Step2 {...this.state} {...this.props} />
            <Step3 {...this.state} {...this.props} />
        </div>
    )
}
```

The `profileSection` router prop gets passed into each of the "step" components. These step components are created from an HOC. The HOC decorates each component with the following behavior:

1. Match a regular expression against the `profileSection` prop.
2. If it matches, the component's render method returns the markup for said step.
3. if it does not match, the component's render method returns null.